# Welche Implementierung des Harvard-Zitationsstils bzgl. Punktsetzung harmoniert mit den grammatischen und orthographischen Regeln des Duden am besten

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Natürlich ist klar, dass es verschiedene Varianten des Harvard-Zitationsstils gibt, die auf Konvention beruhen. Dennoch habe ich mich gefragt, ob hier nicht bestimmte Varianten Elemente einführen, die von den grammatischen und ortographischen Regeln des Duden sehr weit entfernt sind, während es andere Varianten geben mag, die hier dem Duden näherstehen, insbesondere bzgl. der Punktsetzung. Offenbar ist es erlaubt (nicht nur nach Harvard, sondern auch laut Duden), bei einem mehrzeiligen Zitat dieses einzurücken, auf Anführungsstriche zu verzichten und auch das abschließende Satzzeichen vor der Quellenangabe zu setzen. Ein Beispiel:

> Es war einmal vor langer Zeit, da passierte dieses und jenes und auch noch eine ganze Menge mehr, was alles hier in dieses sehr lange Zitat reinpasst. (Autor Jahr, Seitenangabe)

Angenommen ich habe nun ein Zitat, das aus mehreren Sätzen besteht, aber trotzdem insgesamt zu kurz ist, um eingrückt zu werden und somit in den weiteren Text integriert ist. Klar ist, dass in dem Fall Anführungsstriche verwendet werden müssen, aber wie sieht es mit dem abschließenden Satzzeichen aus? Es scheint hier drei Varianten zu geben

> Harvard-Variante 1: "Ich ging nach Hause. Dort angekommen, aß ich etwas" (Autor Jahr, Seitenangabe).

Das scheint die in Ratgebern empfohlene Variante zu sein. Komisch erscheint mir aber, dass hier der letzte abschließende Punkt im Zitat einfach entfernt wird. Das würde man ja in der deutschen Zitierweise nicht machen:

> Deutsche Zitierweise: "Ich ging nach Hause. Dort angekommen, aß ich etwas."²

Hier sind die Anführungsstriche hinter dem Punkt und die Fußnote hinter den Anführungsstrichen, da sich die Fußnote auf das ganze Zitat bezieht.

Eine Alternative im Harvard-Stil, die ich manchmal sehe, ist die folgende:

> Harvard-Variante 2: "Ich ging nach Hause. Dort angekommen, aß ich etwas." (Autor Jahr, Seitenangabe).

Hier werden also zwei(!) Punkte gesetzt, einmal vor den Anführungsstrichen, einmal hinter der Quellenangabe. Das scheint mir eine völlig einzigartige Verwendung des Punktes zu sein und wirkt auf mich dementsprechend komisch. Die dritte Variante wäre meines Erachtens am logischsten:

> Harvard-Variante 3: "Ich ging nach Hause. Dort angekommen, aß ich etwas." (Autor Jahr, Seitenangabe)

Also hier keine Einrückung, aber trotzdem Punkt vor den Anführungsstrichen. Dennoch finde ich diese Variante überwiegend nicht in Ratgebern zum Harvard-Zitationsstil (dort findet sich entweder Einrückung oder aber Entfernung des letzten Punktes vom Zitat). Meine Frage: Welche Implementierung des Harvard-Zitationsstils bzgl. Punktsetzung harmoniert mit den grammatischen und orthographischen Regeln des Duden am besten?

Comment: Die teil erhellenden Kommentare (ich bin nach wie vor der Meinung, dass diese Frage mit „Deutsch“ als Sprache bestenfalls am Rande zu tun hat) waren es wohl nicht wert erhalten zu bleiben … ?

Answer (score 2):

Im Deutschen gelten bei der Rechtschreibung die Regeln, wie sie zum Beispiel in [diesem Duden-Artikel](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/anfuehrungszeichen) zusammengestellt sind. Damit kommt, denke ich, die Möglichkeit, den Punkt aus den Anführungszeichen zu "stehlen", nicht in Frage.

Wenn du noch zusätzlich irgendwo im Harvard-Stil eine Klammer einfügst, sehe ich nicht, dass dadurch ein zusätzlicher Punkt nötig würde. Syntaktisch gehört so eine Klammer mit zusätzlichen Angaben sowieso nicht zum Satz. Von einem Grammatikfehler würde ich deshalb von vorne herein nicht sprechen, das ist eine Orthographiefrage.

In dem Artikel im Duden findet man auch folgendes Beispiel mit zusätzlicher Klammer der Duden-Redaktion:

> „Das muss“, stellte er fest, „jeder für sich selbst entscheiden.“ (Zum Komma D 11.)

Der Punkt in der Klammer passt bei Quellenangaben natürlich nicht, dabei handelt es sich ja nicht um einen Satz, sondern um Angaben mit eigenen Bildungsregeln. Ich sehe auch keinen Grund dafür, dass diese Klammer innerhalb eines Satzes stehen müsste.

Ich finde die dritte Variante also auch am logischsten.